# Modify str in db

Tags: mysql

I have a table, and in one colu,m I store comma separated strings, like:

> book, table, lamp (New)

need to write query loop through all the strings  and remove

> (New)

I think I can do it by first running a query to fetch results containing (New), then using PHP's REGEX, remove (New) and then update the the same row with new string. However this sounds a bit convoluted. Isn't there a way to do this with a single query?

Answer (score 0):

There is a replace string function in mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

```
UPDATE <table> SET <column> = REPLACE(<column>,'(NEW)','')
```

Try it with select first to see if the result is what you want (you may want to remove the trailing space if new is always preceded by it)

Comment: The more I think about this the more I'm convinced I'd have a long way. The (New) could be anywhere in the sting, so I'll need to explode by comma, cleanup and then implode again before saving in db, I think...